# Does this rvalue signature pattern make sense?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

Assume usually I want a copy of the object even if I get a reference. Assume these signatures are within a class scope so that both are seen. What are the pros and cons of doing this as opposed to just having a single push(const RingType& aData). If my object (RingType) only has primitive types or is a primitive type then the pattern probably doesn't buy me anything but does it hurt performance in that case? I feel this pattern is good because if I get a reference I copy it and forward it as an rvalue and if I get an rvalue it just goes to the rvalue signature. Thoughts? My focus here is on performance.

```
void push(const RingType& aData) { 
  push(RingType(aData));
}

void push(RingType&& aData) {
//process aData
}
```

Comment: If you always want a copy you should take the argument by value.

Comment: why use `forward` with lvalue?

Comment: well sometimes you might get a push(Object(x)) but if that Object only contains primitives does this pattern worsen performance?

Comment: Who cares? First make sure the code works correctly - then start the optimization.

Comment: Assume these signatures are in a class body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very useful:

- if you do not need a copy, pass by reference
- if you need a copy, pass by value

In the latter case, the copy constructor or move constructor will be invoked depending on their availability, for optimal performance.